# The effect of parenthesis with `this` binding in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I encounter a very tricky case:

```
class C {
  // class method are implicit in strict mode by default
  static method() { return this === undefined; }  
}

C.method(); // => false
(0,C.method)(); // => true
```

Why `(0, C.method)` changes the binding of `this` in the above case?

Comment: The context changes from the class to global so `this` is undefined.

Comment: You may want to read [the MDN description of how `this` works with object methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method).

Comment: @4castle If a memory is declared and initialized through `var`, it makes sense; but how does the expression `(0, C.method)` allocates new memory slot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `C.method` returns a reference like

```
{ base: C, referencedName: "method", strict: strictFlag }
```

When you [call it](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-function-calls-runtime-semantics-evaluation), JS obtains the function using [GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-getvalue) with that reference, and provides the base of the reference (`C`) as the `this` value.

```
CallExpression : MemberExpression Arguments

 1. Let ref be the result of evaluating MemberExpression. // <-- The reference
 2. Let func be ? GetValue(ref).                          // <-- The function
 4. If Type(ref) is Reference, then
    a. If IsPropertyReference(ref) is true, then
       i. Let thisValue be GetThisValue(ref).             // <-- C
```

However, when you use the [comma operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-comma-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation), you directly get the function, not the reference.

```
Expression : Expression , AssignmentExpression

 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating Expression.
 2. Perform ? GetValue(lref).                             // <-- 0
 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating AssignmentExpression.
 4. Return ? GetValue(rref).                              // <-- The function
```

Since there is no reference, JS can't know the base object, so when you call it provides `undefined` as the `this` value.

```
CallExpression : MemberExpression Arguments

 1. Let ref be the result of evaluating MemberExpression. // <-- The function
 2. Let func be ? GetValue(ref).                          // <-- The function
 5. Else Type(ref) is not Reference,
    1. Let thisValue be undefined.                        // <-- undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comma_operator) in JavaScript, both operands are evaluated, and then the right-most value is returned. The evaluated function value that comes out of the parentheses has no context of where it came from. This can be likened to assigning a value to a variable, where the right-hand side of the assignment operator `=` is evaluated before the value is assigned:

```
(0, C.method)();
//  ^^^^^^^^ evaluates here

var func = C.method;
//         ^^^^^^^^ evaluates here
func();
```

Once a function is put into a variable, it loses all context of what object it came from (unless `bind` is used). This context is important to [determining the value of `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method). When a function is called without being the member of an object, it defaults to the global object, or `undefined` if the function is in strict mode. ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Simple_call))