# Trouble in understanding this syntax in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
var log = (0, _lodash.memoize)(function (message) {
  console.log((0, _ansicolors.red)('WARNING:'), message);
});
```

I am facing difficulty in understanding the above code. This code was written in JavaScript.

Comment: Is it the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) which you're asking about?

Comment: my understand is that a function is passed to lodash memoize method as parameter and what that '0' is doing? i may be wrong...

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41529801/5743988) will show what purpose the `0` might have. Hint: the zero could have been any value. It's the comma which has special behavior.

Comment: @4castle . Great example.

Comment: you may have here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076794/does-the-comma-operator-influence-the-execution-context-in-javascript a look too.

Comment: Thanks @NinaScholz

Answer (score 1):

Basically the code `(0, _lodash.memoize)` eliminates the need to make a new `instance` and directly gives you the value of function rather than reference.